# Why does eclipse limit the AVD choices to only target API when another device is running?

Tags: android, eclipse, adt, android-virtual-device

For example, if I have my minSdkVersion="4" in the manifest, set project properties specify a build target that uses API level 15, and have a manual target selection mode in my Run Configurations, when I first try to run the project all my virtual devices from API 4-15 are visible.  But after starting one of them up, when I try to run again and start a different instance, the only AVDs available to choose are the running device and those using the target API 15.  Same thing if I have connected a physical device via USB.  But if I kill/disconnect all the devices, the full list returns again.  Why is that and is there a way to make the eligible devices always show?

Right now I've been firing up the AVD manager and manually starting any extra device, so that it appears in the list of running devices to deploy to.  Kind of annoying if I want to toy with multiple AVDs at the same time.  This is with Eclipse 3.7.1 and ADT 16.

Comment: Same for me, except its worse, doesn't even show the 4-15 avds at first run. Bug imho. ADT 17.